# How to return a pointer to a ragged array through a function argument?

Tags: c++

I need to modifiy an existing API and basically the only option I have is returning a pointer to a ragged array through a function argument (this would normally not be me personal preference). I can't get my head around doing this and keep getting a segmentation fault at this part of the code:

```
void getMxByArg(int ***pppX) {
    *pppX = m_ppMx; // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
}
```

I've provided an example below which doesn't have any external dependencies and encapsulates the problem.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Mx {
public:
    Mx() {
        int *buff01 = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
        int *buff02 = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

        buff01[0] = 0;
        buff01[1] = 1;
        buff01[2] = 3;

        buff02[0] = 4;
        buff02[1] = 5;
        buff02[2] = 6;

        m_n = 2;
        m_ppMx = (int**)malloc(m_n * sizeof(int*));
        m_ppMx[0] = buff01;
        m_ppMx[1] = buff02;
    }

    ~Mx() {
        for (int i=0; i<m_n; ++i) {
            free(m_ppMx[i]);
        }
        free(m_ppMx);
    }

    int** getMx() {
        return m_ppMx;
    }

    void getMxByArg(int ***pppX) {
        *pppX = m_ppMx; // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
    }

private:
    int **m_ppMx;
    int m_n;
};

int main()
{
    Mx mx;

    // SUCCESS
    int **ppX = mx.getMx();

    // FAILURE, Results in segmentation fault in getMxByArg
    int ***pppX;
    mx.getMxByArg(pppX);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pppx;` is not initialized.  It does not point to a valid memory address, and you are dereferencing it.

Comment: Is this really valid c? I have my doubts.

Comment: You'd have: `int** ppX; getMxByArg(&ppX);`

Comment: @AndrasDeak It's not C at all, it's C++! We have class, constructor, access control...

Comment: @Andras, why do you have doubts? I compile as follows: g++ -v -g -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.o (the c++11 flag is probably not necessary))

Comment: In C++, you should prefer `new <whatever>[<length>]` to allocate arrays and `delete[]` to free them again - instead of (good old?) C API (malloc/free).

Comment: @Jejo yes I agree on that, however it's not possible for me to use std::vector in the codebase I'm working on (the example above is only provided in order to demonstrate the problem)

Comment: By the way, in C++, you can overload, i. e. you can have both `int** getMx();` and `void getMx(int*** x);` at the same time. If this makes sense or not is use case dependent, though...

Comment: You never. Never. **EVER**. Pass an uninitialised value to a C function (Or a C++ function except when it's passed by reference).

Comment: @n.m. "except when it's passed by reference": [...], but only, if it is the functions's explicit purpose to initialise the reference; but then you can pass uninitialised `x` to such a function in C as well (indirectly), if it is in the following form: `int x; f(&x);`...

Comment: @Aconcagua No, you are not passing an uninitialised variable to `f`, you are passing an expression `&x`. `&x` is not a variable. `x` is.

Comment: @n.m. Technically, I don't see any difference in between passing by pointer or passing by reference, in either case, under the hoods it's the variable's address that is passed...  Am I looking to far into direction of compiler design???

Comment: I prefer to use precise names instead of feel-good warm fuzzy monikers. C doesn't have pass by reference, it only has pass by value. When you want to simulate some of the effect of pass by reference that exists in other languages, you pass an address of the variable, but the syntax is different enough to deserve a separate name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the posted code, you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. That's cause for undefined behavior.

The solution is:

1. Create a variable of type `int**`.
2. Pass the address of that variable to the function.

---

```
int **ppX2;
mx.getMxByArg(&ppX2);
```

---

Another option is to change the argument type to `int**&`.

```
void getMxByArg(int**& ppX) {
    ppX = m_ppMx;
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
int **ppX2;
mx.getMxByArg(ppX2);
```

Comment: That indeed works :). Is there perhaps a more user-friendly way? I.e. now I have to inform the API user that he must pass the argument with '&', I would preferably avoid that.

Comment: @Gio With pointers: No... This is how in general pointers work if you want to have them as return value arguments, simplified version: `void f(int* x) { *x = 7; }` You need to let x point to some valid int for that you can dereference! More user-friendly are references, though: `void f(int**& x) { x = yourArray; }`, this one you *can* call like `int** x; f(x);`.

Comment: @Gio If you are writing a C-compatible function that must initialise its argument, you have no choice but inform the users they have to use `&`. There's just no other way to do that in C. If C compatibility is not your goal and you can change the signature, just use `std::vector`.